# Is there a better way for drawing my table

Tags: tables

I've made a table with repeating empty cells so I was wondering if there is a better way to draw it.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{11pt}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|c|}
            \cline{3-22}

            & & \multicolumn{20}{ c| }{\LARGE Joueurs} \\ \cline{3-22}

            & & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} \\ \cline{1-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{20}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LARGE Cartes}} } &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 10}} & ~~~
            & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & ~~~ \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 9}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 8}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 7}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 6}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 5}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 4}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 3}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 2}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{2-24}

            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 1}} &
            & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}


            \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{}  \\ \cline{1-22}

    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Compliments for your table. 2. Should the cells remain empty (that is, is this only a scheme which will be filled in manually by the players) or will you have to put some text inside?

Comment: If they should stay empty, you might define a macro which generetes one row and use it for each row.

Comment: @CarLaTeX 1. Thank you. 2. Yes, the cells should remain empty.

Comment: 1. You're welcome :):):) 2. Do you like Mico's answer or do you have other requests?

Comment: I like Mico's answer, but I'd like to try it before voting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there's a lot of repeated or recurring material, it's a good idea to set up macros to handle the recurring parts of the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,graphicx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{11pt}

%% Define a few macros to handle recurring material
\newcommand\myheader[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE #1}}}
\newcommand\manyamps{%
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\}
\newcommand\manyclines{%
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} 
    \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}}
\newcommand\manymulticols{%
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\}
\newcommand\myline[1]{% combine the four preceding macros
    \myheader{#1}\manyamps\manyclines\manymulticols}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\noindent % <--- new
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc| *{10}{c|X|} c|c|}
    \cline{3-22}
    & & \multicolumn{20}{c|}{\LARGE Joueurs} \\ 
    \cline{3-22}

    & & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} 
      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} 
      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} \\ 
    \hline %%\cline{1-24}

    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LARGE Cartes}} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE 10}} 
    & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & 
    & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ &   ~~~ \\ 
    \manyclines\manymulticols \cline{2-24}

    % Use the "\myline" macro for rows 9, 8, ..., 2, 1.
    \myline{9} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{8} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{7} \cline{2-22} % not "2-24"
    \manymulticols \cline{2-24}
    \myline{6} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{5} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{4} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{3} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{2} \cline{2-24}
    \myline{1} \cline{1-22} % not "2-24"
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the macros. I am fairly new to latex. Thank you!